# PHPEclipse weird highlight

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

This is not a technical problem, but very annoying.

Does anyone know how to turn off or change the color for the name highlight in phpEclipse?

I use white-on-black scheme and this highlight has a white background which makes it unreadable and very ugly.

To better explain which highlight I'm refering to, it's when I move the cursor to a variable/function/method/constant, all other places that name is typed get highlighted.

I've spent a few days going thru the settings many, many times and I haven't found one that changes that specific annoying highligh.

Anyone? please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java in Eclipse it is:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences.

My ruby plug-in has the same option.  Do a search in the preferences window for 'Mark Occurrences' and hopefully the php plug-in has the same option.

Comment: This feature was disabled in Eclipse 3.4 with PHPeclipse earlier than 1.2.

"PHPeclipse release 1.2.1 fixes an issue with Eclipse 3.4. When you select a word all the occurrences of that word were not highlighted."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was it, Mark Occurences.

When I searched thru the options I was looking for color pickers instead of checkboxes :)

It would be nicer to be able to change the highlight color for that, but even removing it is of huge help.

Answer (score -1):

From Eclipse, go to Window > Preference, use the filter field ("type filter text") to search for "color". It will show all the config options related to the colors.

I suppose it's not a problem with phpEclipse, but an incompatibility with another Eclipse plugin.

PS: When you fix the problem please tell us what that setting!